# Flutter Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I made a function to post some data using http.post, when using the function i pass as parameter the id, now im using this function in other places but it says that it has 1 positional argument but 0 found.

```
Future<Response?> postLocationId(String id) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
    var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/$id/workingTimeframes';
    try {
      response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString(),
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      );
    } catch (er) {}

    return response;
  }

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchWorkingLocationData();
    futureDataForAccount = fetchAccountData();
    futureDataForStatus = postLocationId(id); <<<< getting error here
  }

                             ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {  
                           final WorkingLocationData locationData =
                                    workingData!.firstWhere(
                                        (some) => some.id == 
                                         chooseLocation);
                                await postLocationId(locationData.id); <<<
```

Comment: Where in your code define your id for this line -> futureDataForStatus = postLocationId(id); <<<< getting error here

Comment: at the end of the code i passed as a parameter location.id

Comment: basically i want to use postLocationId() but im getting the error becauses on the function you have id as parameter

Comment: And where you get a locationData.id?

Comment: Can you post your full code, especially, where do you get `id`? Because from your code, it looks like `id` doesnt have any value on it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is because you are passed a parameter (id == null) that doesn’t exist before **initState()**,

If you try and change the id word for a '1' string, this work, but doesnt the better solution.

You need to modify your logic in your initState() because you pass an argument that is null you have a lot of options:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocationData():
}

void getLocationData() async {
  final locationData = {...} // This return location data information
  postLocationId(locationData.id) 
}
```

or You can omit the end line in your initState()

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchWorkingLocationData();
    futureDataForAccount = fetchAccountData();
    // futureDataForStatus = postLocationId(id);
}
```

Edit your logic inside your onPressed function to this:

final locationData =
workingData!.firstWhere((some) => some.id == chooseLocation);

```
if (locationData != null) {
  await postLocationId(locationData.id);
  setState(() {
    _flag = !_flag;
  });
} else {
  print('locationData is null);
}
```

Comment: here is the full code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CfCbPk3z

Comment: @Ajan code updated, add a validation inside Elevated Button function.

Comment: its a compile time error if im trying to use getLocationData() in initstate, since the method is declared inside the build method